# Accessing form by ID

Tags: javascript, dom

The line below (allegedly) looks for a form with id `frm1` ([W3S source](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp)).

```
var x = document.forms["frm1"];
```

Why should it even work? If you look in the [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_forms.asp), `document.forms` returns the collection of forms. There are no associative arrays in JS, so `document.forms["frm1"]` basically asks for a property called `frm1` of the returned collection. I think the right way is to use `namedItem("frm1")`.

Is it merely a mistake in this tutorial, maybe something that worked in the past and is no longer valid?

Comment: It's a feature at least in `forms` and `frames` collections. Originally `name` was used instead of `id` to identify a partucular form, and some browsers might still have stucked to the original implementation. Please see the documentation of [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). In the example code there's `document.forms.myForm;`, which is a variation of what you have.

Comment: @Teemu So basically this reference is incomplete? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_forms.asp It doesn't mention it at all.

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @user107986 Yes, w3schools is not the best possible source of documentation, as you can read in the article KingCodeFish has linked above.

Comment: @KingCodeFish w3fools has not complained about w3schools in years. There is nothing wrong with using them as a reference.

Comment: @Rob I'm not saying that they haven't improved. I'm just saying that MDN has a more complete resource of information.

Answer (score 0):

As @Teemu pointed out, the answer you're looking for lies here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

> HTMLCollection.namedItem()
>   Returns the specific node whose ID or, as a fallback, name matches the string specified by name. Matching by name is only done as a last resort, only in HTML, and only if the referenced element supports the name attribute. Returns null if no node exists by the given name.

While this is true and works fine for ID's when given a string, it also supports indices:

> HTMLCollection also exposes its members directly as properties by both name and index. HTML IDs may contain : and . as valid characters, which would necessitate using bracket notation for property access. Currently HTMLCollections does not recognize purely numeric IDs, which would cause conflict with the array-style access, though HTML5 does permit these.

As you can see, there are problems present with mixing ID and index together. But this allowed it to have a short and sweet syntax as you can see. HTML5 has eased up the strictness, but conflicts can result.

Comment: Your statement about w3schools is misleading, based on out of date information you gleaned from w3fools. Even w3fools no longer complains about past issues with w3schools and you should not parrot old information.

Comment: The basic reason why OP's example works, is that, the returned `HTMLCollection` is a host object. Host objects are allowed to have methods and properties which native JS objects don't have.